# MySQL find which data inserted in which place

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know whether it is possible to find the row and column affected by an `INSERT`.

The data is read from a file and I want to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicates, just add appropriate `INDEX` `UNIQUE` clauses.

The closest thing to an "inserted row id" you can get with `LAST_INSERT_ID()` after declaring an appropriate `AUTO_INCREMENT` [column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) key (thanks @mvp!).

If you use the `INSERT IGNORE` syntax, data will be automatically made unique, i.e., duplicate rows will be silently ignored and not inserted. You may also want to look at the `ON DUPLICATE KEY...` [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for `INSERT`.

As for which columns are affected by an insert, that's easy -- *all* of them :-)

Comment: Really? `last_insert_id()` would only exist if primary auto increment integer key was defined

Comment: Right, I rewrote it better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the same data again, you could have a look at adding [Primary Keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html) to your tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ServerLog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html) to protocol statements, or set a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) on all your tables which inserts protocols about all inserts in a Log table where you write the inserted columns/raws.

Answer (score 0):

If you have unknown SQL statements which you will exceute in a batch process, you could parse on the fly your SQL statements to find out, which columns are used.